# Can I 'encourage' PHP engine to use CPU more freely?

Tags: php, performance, cpu

Can I 'encourage' PHP engine to use CPU more freely? Yeah. Just that. Is that possible? My problem is, that when I look at the CPU usage it's nearly 0, not affected by the server, even when there's a connection timeout like `Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded`.

Comment: How do you know you're CPU-bound?

Comment: What's the script doing? Loading/saving files? HTTP requests? Juggling GBs of RAM? sleep()ing? :)

Comment: Mostly, it's working with MySQL. I think this is the real issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're most likely waiting on something *else* like disk I/O, database queries, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Any PHP script will grab as much CPU time as it can; as will most applications, most of the time.

If your cpu usage (or at least one core) is not 100% while your PHP script is running, it means that something else is preventing it from doing so. In most cases this is IO (memory, disk, network).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can effect PHP's CPU usage in the way you want - it will use as much as the OS allows it to. Internally, you can edit these php.ini params to help manage performance:

max_execution_time = 30
max_input_time = 30
memory_limit = 40M
post_max_size = 8M
upload_max_filesize = 2M